# ALT to lightbox with the popup image to be linked by a button in the image not in a caption

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Here is my image I want to use:

[image]

I am seeking a way to use a js plugin similar to lightbox, but which will allow the popup image to contain a button with  to another page. If you were to have any js that works I am all ears. Thank you!!!

Example of my "popup" image using lightbox. I would like the "LEARN MORE NOW" to be linked to that finance page

Comment: Easiest way is to use html for this.

Comment: OK, I was hoping for a JS answer, but will have to use HTML. Thank you.